# Change content of MySQL table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am using wordpress site. Pages and their content are stored in MySQL database.

I would like to create PHP function which would do query to MySQL table and changes content (in MySQL table) between `<span>` tags with specific ID. Plus this function evaluates what is between `<span>` and accordingly changes content (Changes text from "Available" to "Unavailable" and vice versa).

Here is example:

```
<span id="text1">Available</span>

//Function searches for tag with id "text1", checks text is "Available/Unavailable" and changes to opposite.

<span id="text1">Unavailable</span>
```

Sorry if I didnt explain this clearly.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: [php-mysql-tutorial](https://www.udemy.com/php-mysql-tutorial/)

Comment: If you intend to be changing the value of 'available' often, you'd do better to put it in its own field.  Text search and replace is expensive and error prone.  If this is a one time thing,  read the MySQL docs about `REGEX` (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)